# |as_crispy_field got passed an invalid or inexistent field

Tags: python, django

tengo un problema en mi codigo, me dice que es del formulario crispy_form pero el error me indica que es de mi views. Este es mi codigo:

**views.py**

```
    my_form  = AlumnoForm()
    my_form2 = ApoderadoForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        my_form = AlumnoForm(request.POST) and ApoderadoForm(request.POST)
        if my_form.is_valid() and my_form2.is_valid():
            print(my_form.cleaned_data)
            print(my_form2.cleaned_data)
            Alumno.objects.create(**my_form.cleaned_data)
            Apoderado.objects.create(**my_form2.cleaned_data)
            return redirect('listar_alumnos')
        else:
            print(my_form.errors)
            print(my_form2.errors)

    extra_context = {
        'form' : my_form,
        'form2': my_form2
    }
    return render(request, "crear_alumno.html", extra_context)
```

El error me indica que es en la ultima linea de views.py, el template me funciona normalmente y con dos formularios pero al momento de guardar me da el error de  `|as_crispy_field got passed an invalid or inexistent field`

Este es el form de alumno y apoderados para las dudas, mas abajo compartiré el template:

form:

```
    class Meta:
        model = Alumno
        fields = [
            'Nombre_alumno',
            'Rut_alumno',
            'Edad',
            'Fecha_nacimiento',
            'categoria_inscripcion'
        ]
        widgets = {
            'Nombre_alumno'             : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','size': '60','placeholder': 'Escribir aquí'}),
            'Rut_alumno'             : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','size': '60','placeholder': 'Escribir aquí'}),
            'Edad'                      : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','size': '60','placeholder': 'Escribir aquí'}),
            'Fecha_nacimiento'          : forms.DateTimeInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','type':'date'}),
            'categoria_inscripcion'     : forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control','size': '1','placeholder': 'Escribir aquí'})
        }
        labels = {
            "Rut_alumno"                : "<br> Rut Alumno",
            "Edad"                      : "<br> Edad Alumno",
            "Fecha_nacimiento"          : "<br> Fecha nacimiento Alumno",
            "categoria_inscripcion"     : "<br> Categoria inscripcion Alumno",
        }


class ApoderadoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta: 
        model = Apoderado 
        fields = [
            'Nombre_apoderado',
            'Rut_apoderado',
            'Direccion',
            'Telefono',
        ]
        widgets = {
            'Nombre_apoderado' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','size': '60','placeholder': 'Escribir aquí'}),
            'Rut_apoderado'    : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','size': '60','placeholder': 'Escribir aquí'}),
            'Direccion'        : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','size': '60','placeholder': 'Escribir aquí'}),
            'Telefono'         : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','size': '60','placeholder': 'Escribir aquí'}),
        }
        labels = {
            "Nombre_Apoderado" : "<br> Nombre Apoderado",
            "Rut_apoderado"    : "<br> Rut Apoderado",
            "Direccion"        : "<br> Direccion Apoderado",
            "Telefono"         : "<br> Telefono Apoderado",
        }
```

A continuacion se mostrara el template en el cual realize dos formularios que es el de alumno y el de apoderado:

template:

````
{% load static %}
{% block contenedor %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/crear_alumno.css' %}">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="{% static '/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
</head>


<form action='.' method='POST' class="formulario"> 
    <div class="fonts">
        <h1 class="display-4" style="color: #f8f9fa">Alumno <i class="fas fa-child"></i></h1>
        <br>
    </div>
    <div style="color: #f8f9fa">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-0">
            {{ form2.Nombre_apoderado|as_crispy_field }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-0">
            {{ form.Nombre_alumno|as_crispy_field }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-4 mb-0">
            {{ form2.Direccion|as_crispy_field }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-2 mb-0">
            {{ form2.Telefono|as_crispy_field }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-2 mb-0">
            {{ form2.Rut_apoderado|as_crispy_field }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-2 mb-0">
            {{ form.Rut_alumno|as_crispy_field }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-2 mb-0">
            {{ form.Fecha_nacimiento|as_crispy_field }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-2 mb-0">
            {{ form.Edad|as_crispy_field }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-2 mb-0">
            {{ form.categoria_inscripcion|as_crispy_field }}
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <br><br>
    <input type='submit' class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg btn-block" value='Guardar' />
</form>

{% endblock %} ```
````

Comment: Puedes compartir, el form y el template?

Comment: Necesitas dar mayor contexto explicando el problema presentado y no solamente código, ya que si solo pones un inmenso script por eso el sistema no te lo permite, edita y solo coloca lo que realmente sea relevante al problema tanto en explicación como en código

Comment: @Riaven Edite mi publicacion y comparti el form y template.

Comment: @Aprendiz Si eso me di cuenta, ya logre solucionarlo muchas gracias de todas maneras.